# How to find a string within a string in C?

Tags: c, c-strings

First, I have already tried using the `strstr()` method that has been mentioned here, but this is not working for the problem I am trying to solve.

I am to obtain an input string from the user (the target string), which can be a word or a full sentence. It then scans an input text file line-by-line and checks if this input string exists in any lines of the file. If so, the corresponding text file line number and the full text file line in which the target string can be found is printed to the screen.

My problem while using the `strstr(line, targetString)` method is as follows:
Let's presume there is a sentence in the file, "I vigorously slapped that fish with a squirrel." Then, I enter my target string as, "I frolicked about the cat graveyard with unrelenting glee." It will show that the target string was matched, presumably because it is just finding a match with the "I". However, I need it to match only when it matches word-for-word of the target string to some substring within the text file line.

Any ideas how I might go about this? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
FILE *inputFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

i = 1;
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, inputFile) != NULL)
{
    if ((strlen(line) != 1) && (strstr(line, targetString)))
    {
        printf("Line %d: ", i);
        printf("%s\n\n", line);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Good question with proper explanation. It would be better if you post some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: How are you getting input? If you are using `scanf` then you are only reading the first word of the input which is why it's only matching on that.

Comment: The [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) will only return "true" (a non-null pointer) if the second string is fully in the first string. If those two sentences you show match, then you're doing something wrong, but we can't say what without seeing any code.

Comment: You are doing something wrong, which is not apparent from the question. Please write a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1) show the input file _exactly_ as it is for your described problem.  2) show the code snippet containing the relevant code _exactly_ as it is used in your failing application.  Only then can someone give a meaningful, accurate reply.

Comment: Returns NULL: http://codepad.org/sEe55ZNY

Comment: Code entry of "target string" is wrong and is only `"I"`.  Post code.

Answer (score 2):

strstr() should work for your problem. Make sure both of the arguments actually have spaces and not \0 characters. strstr() like many standard C library functions treats \0 as a string terminator. Based on your description, I am going to guess the problem is that you read one line at a time and terminate each with a \0, then start matching one line at a time. You might be able to solve your problem if you read all of the strings at once into a buffer equal to the size of the file removing newline characters.

To be able to answer your question better, I would need to see your current source code with a test case that you expect to work.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem while using the strstr(line, targetString) method is as follows: Let's presume there is a sentence in the file, "I vigorously slapped that fish with a squirrel." Then, I enter my target string as, "I frolicked about the cat graveyard with unrelenting glee." It will show that the target string was matched, presumably because it is just finding a match with the "I".

This is not how `strstr` works.  It doesn't match the first word/letter, it matches the entire string.

Comment: While helpful, this is not an answer - it should be a comment instead.

Comment: It is an answer, because `strstr` is indeed the function that OP wants to accomplish their goal.

Comment: As written, all you're doing is pointing out a bad assumption by OP, not explaining why the function should in fact solve their problem.  In any case, the bad assumption shows that the problem probably doesn't really have anything to do with string matching specifically, and requires further investigation.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's presume there is a sentence in the file, "I vigorously slapped that fish with a squirrel." Then, I enter my target string as, "I frolicked about the cat graveyard with unrelenting glee." It will show that the target string was matched, presumably because it is just finding a match with the "I".

It sounds like you're interpreting the result of `strstr()` as an index into the string in question, but in fact the result is a `char *`, i.e. a *pointer* to the first match in the string. The `0` that you're getting back isn't the index the the first character, it's `nil`, meaning that there was no match.

Comment: `nil` is more commonly called `NULL` in C. From [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr), "... or `NULL` if no match is found.."